# Equation satisfied by a heat reservoir in statistical mechanics

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, temperature

In the following image (from Reif's Fundamentals of Statistical and Thermal Physics), how does the condition of a heat reservoir, i.e., its temperature remains essentially unchanged irrespective of any amount of heat Q' which it may absorb, lead to 3.6.1 (where beta = 1/k*temperature)?[image]

Comment: Please use MathJax and don't post images, but rather use the quote function, see [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the fragment quoted, reservoir is very big compared to the system, so that one can ignore the changes that happen in it when it absorbs*any amount of heat that a system can provide*. In other words, *any* here needs to be understood in the context provided by the preceding sentence.

Comment: But what does (dB'/dE')Q' mean?

Comment: @Qwertyuiop that the change of (inverse) temperature is much smaller than its value. Assume that $\beta'$ is a function of energy and expand in Taylor series: $\beta'(E'+Q')$.